# During MSSQL import script, how can I know to which column the error is referring?

Tags: sql-server, import

I am running the following script and getting an error. Problem is I don't know in which column is the problem:

```
        INSERT INTO D_ParcelLocationEXT (ParcelCounter, ProductGroupID, LabAccountID, CertificateNo, CertificateDate, CertificateTypeID, ReportNo, JobNo, LabComments, PaintComments, RShapeID, RSizeID, RColorID, RClarityID, RQualityID, LShapeID, LSizeID, LColorID, LClarityID, LQualityID, EstimateLColorID, EstimateLClarityID, Measurements1, Measurements2, Measurements3, Depth, StoneTable, CrownAngle, CrownHeight, PavillionAngle, PavillionDepth, StarLength, LowerHalf, GirdleMinMax, OpticalBrilliant, Inscription, ForeverMark, GirdleID, CuletID, PolishID, SymmetryID, FluorescenceID, FluorescenceColorID, CuletStatusID, GirdleConditionID, ClarityStatusID, ProportionID, PaintingID, CutGradeID, OpticalSymmetryID, OpticalBrilliantID, LGirdleID, LCuletID, LPolishID, LSymmetryID, LFluorescenceID, LFluorescenceColorID, LCuletStatusID, LGirdleConditionID, LClarityStatusID, LProportionID, LPaintingID, LCutGradeID, LOpticalSymmetryID, LOpticalBrilliantID, QualityRuleID, ListCostPercentRuleID, ListSalePercentRuleID, NewStatus)

    SELECT Autonumbering, 'POLISHED', LabID, '', 0, '','','','', [Paint Comments], Shape, Size, Color, Clarity,'', Shape, Size, Color, Clarity,'','','', M1, M2, M3, Depth, StoneTable, [Crown Angle], [Crown Height], [Pavillion Angle], [Pavillion Depth], '', [Lower Half],'', 0, '','', '', CuletID, Polish, SYM, FluorescenceID, '','', '','','','',Cut,'','', '', CuletID, Polish, SYM, FluorescenceID, '','', '','','','',Cut,'','', 0, 0, 0, 0

FROM sometable
```

The error I get is:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 12 Error converting data type
>   varchar to numeric.

This is a common problem for me, when I am using import scripts, I never know where is the problem exactly. How can I found out in an effective way?

Thanks

Comment: You won't, however, I would suggest starting with the columns in your table `D_ParcelLocationEXT` that are defined as a `numeric`, and then looking at the columns you are inserting (from your table `sometable`); at least one of them won't be a `numeric` and then you likely have your culprit.

Comment: I'd get some formatting and aliasing in the query as well, to make marrying the columns a lot easier: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6b6808c27c67687129cd7df7b3f3c8a0)

Comment: I pasted them into excel and did TEXT TO COLUMNS. then I could see them one under another.
I tried replacing all the numeric columns (decimal and int) to import 0, instead of the column names (to know for sure that the problem is not coming from the source table) and I still get this error..

Comment: I have checked now and in D_ParcelLocationEXT there's not a single numeric column, there are many int and decimal columns. are they also counted as numeric? I am really confused now..

Comment: `decimal` = `numeric`; the 2 words are synonyms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. One of the columns that was imported was empty and SQL decided it to be nvarchar.. don't understand what's so difficult to give the column name in the error message. not everything needs to be a struggle.. – Vladi 19 mins ago   Delete